# Twig: compiled C extension performance

Tags: php, performance, symfony, twig

I compiled the twig C extension for my PHP / IIS (5.6.11, nts, x86) and activated it with success: I can see it in `phpinfo()`.

But it has absolutely no impact on performance, neither in development or production mode, whereas I have collection of hundreds of Symfony2 forms (that use Twig a lot).

What is the use case, or is there anything else to do?

Comment: Does PHP load Twig from the PHP extension of from your files? Did you configure this? (these are naive questions, I don't know this subject)

Comment: According to http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/installation.html, "And from now on, Twig will automatically compile your templates to take advantage of the C extension. Note that this extension does not replace the PHP code but only provides an optimized version of the Twig_Template::getAttribute() method." so it should be automatic

Comment: I also found that the getAttribute method is slow and I overloaded the template of few widgets to avoid the use of this method and I hard-coded the attributes I need. So I think should see the difference (for example for a list of 350 objects, each object having 3 input => getAttributes is called 1050 times so I should see a slight impact)

Comment: The page says *The C extension is optional but it brings some nice performance improvements.*. So seeing no improvement is probably not expected.

Answer (score 2):

After enabling the C extension, you need to clear your Symfony cache to force Twig to recompile all templates. Otherwise the optimized version will not be used. This is the only thing needed to make Twig use the extension.

However, if you render Symfony forms, the main bottleneck may be located in the form system rather than in the access to attributes in Twig (the Symfony form theme is using very few accesses to attributes with the Twig system, it passes almost all necessary data as variables in the context).

If you face performance issue, the right solution is to profile your code to know where the bottlenecks really are, which will tell you where things can be optimized. One free tool available for that is [Blackfire](https://blackfire.io/) done by SensioLabs, which is very easy to use (it does not work for servers running on Windows though, so it may not suit you given that you say you use IIS). There are also other alternatives available (XHProf for instance).

Comment: Note in the latest versions of Twig (since 1.22.3), Twig takes the availability of the C extension into account when computing the cache key for a template, so the cache will be invalidated automatically when enabling the C extension